# ¿Cómo ordenar una parte de un diccionario?

Tags: python, python-3.x, diccionarios

Quiero ordenar una parte de un diccionario que se compone de una clave que siempre es la misma y de cadenas como valores, lo que he hecho hasta el momento creo que no me da el resultado esperado:

```
import operator      
inven={'gold':500,'pouch':['flint','twine','gemstone'],'backpack': 
['xylophone','dagger','bedroll','bread loaf']}           
inven['pocket']=['seahell','strange berry','lint']
for i in inven['backpack']:
    backpack_ord=(sorted(inven.items(),key=operator.itemgetter(0)))
print backpack_ord
```

El resultado de este código es el siguiente:

```
[('backpack', ['xylophone', 'dagger', 'bedroll', 'bread loaf']), ('gold', 500), ('pocket', ['seahell', 'strange berry', 'lint']), ('pouch', ['flint', 'twine', 'gemstone'])]
```

Sinceramente creo que no está bien, si alguien me puede echar una mano se lo agradecería
Saludos

Comment: ¿Pero lo que he hecho es correcto?¿ha ordenado atendiendo a los valores que son cadenas? Con los listas se podía ordenar alfabéticamente las cadenas con sorted y he pensado que también se podía aquí

Comment: Gracias entonces, muchas gracias

Comment: @Benito-B eso cambió en Python! a partir de ahora Python guarda por orden de insercción los pares clave:valor . Por lo que se pueden usar ordenados!!

Comment: Efectivamente, a partir de la 3.7 python recuerda el orden de los elementos en un diccionario. No lo sabía @RubialesAlberto!

Comment: ¿`print backpack_ord` se trata de la versión 2 de python? ¿Tampoco me queda claro que es lo que quieres ordenado? ¿las claves del diccionario? ¿Los elementos de las listas en `backpack`?

Comment: Ya lo solucioné, me fui por la calle sencilla, lo convertí en lista y utilicé sorted, muchas gracias a todos, soy un novato en esto y algunas cosas de explicáis se me escapan.......ahora en breve va otra pregunta.Muchas gracias por todo

Answer (score 3):

Primero te voy a dar la solución rápida a tu problema y después una explicación detallada de todo:

**Advertencia:** Necesitas tener la versión 3.7 de Python o superior.

La forma más sencilla de ordenar un diccionario es usando la función **built-in** `sorted()` como tú intentas, sin embargo te falta usar una función `lambda` por ejemplo, para poder acceder al tipo de dato por el que quieras ordenarlo. En este ejemplo te lo pongo ordenado por la clave del diccionario:

```
inven={'gold':500,'pouch':['flint','twine','gemstone'],'backpack': 
['xylophone','dagger','bedroll','bread loaf']}           
inven['pocket']=['seahell','strange berry','lint']

invent_ordenado = {k: v for k, v in sorted(x.items(), key=lambda item: item[0])}
```

y te daría el siguiente **output**:

```
{'backpack': ['xylophone', 'dagger', 'bedroll', 'bread loaf'],
 'gold': 500,
 'pocket': ['seahell', 'strange berry', 'lint'],
 'pouch': ['flint', 'twine', 'gemstone']}
```

### Explicación del ejemplo:

1. Usamos la función `sorted()` para ordenar.
2. `x.items()`: nos devuelve una tupla con las clave:valor del diccionario.
3. `key=`: el argumento de `sorted()` en el cual queremos fijarnos para ordenar.
4. `lambda item: item[0]`: en este caso con `lambda` cogemos cada par clave:valor que ahora lo llamo **"item"** y le digo que quiero seleccionar la clave mediante slicing `item[0]`.
5. Por último utilizo **dict comprehension** para devolver los valores en forma de diccionario ordenado.

### Sobre la ordenación de diccionarios. (si ya es posible ordenarlos)

Aunque historicamente, los diccionarios no podían ser ordenados, **a partir de Phython 3.7 sí se pueden ordenar**, y Python garantiza que respetará el orden de inserción clave:valor en nuestro diccionario. Incluso la propia documentación de Python nos recomienda usar la función `sorted()` que se ha usado en este ejemplo, [aquí está la documentación](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

También se puede ver en los famosos **what's New in Python 3.x** dejo más documentación [aquí.](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html)

Incluso si eres curioso, tienes la cadena de correos que mantuvieron todos los que estuvieron involucrados en esta actualización para los diccionarios. En ella se puede ver como se debate acerca de su velocidad, sobre `OrderecDict()`, y más temas al respecto y se pueden sacar varias conclusiones. Puedes ver estos correos [aquí.](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html) en los que interviene hasta Guido Van Rossum (Creador del lenguaje) aunque te voy a resumir como se ha hecho:

Se introdució en Cpython 3.6 y se agrego en Python 3.7, las diferencias entre los dos diccionarios son:

- **Antiguo diccionario**: es una tabla hash de tipo sparse que contiene claves y valores en un orden seudo aleatorio calculado a partir de la clave
- **Nuevo diccionario:** esta compuesto en dos partes. Ahora la tabla hash se encarga de ser un indice, que mantiene el orden de insercción en el diccionario, mientras que las clave:valor se encuentran en un array denso.

Para una mejor comprensión adjunto un dibujo que he hecho de los dos diccionarios.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, aunque de algunas cosas que dices ahí, no me entero muy bien.Saludos

Comment: Mientras que el código te funcione, me alegro que te haya servido! Como eres nuevo posiblemente no lo sepas, pero la mejor forma de dar las gracias en StackOverflow si la respuesta te ha servido, es marcarla como "respuesta correcta", y por qué no, votarla positivamente. Esto no solo recompensará a la persona que te ha respondido por el esfuerzo que ha realizado si no que ayudará a que la pregunta se posicione mejor y sea más fácil de encontrar para personas que tengan el mismo problema que tú.

Comment: Lo de respuesta correcta es en el triángulo, ¿no? y el voto supongo que en el botón que lo pone, aunque yo le doy y no me parece que haga esa acción