# Conseguir la clave de un diccionario a traves de su posicion en el diccionario

Tags: python, diccionarios

Basicamente es saber cual es el metodo para conseguir la clave de un diccionario a traves de su posicion.

```
Personal = {
"test": {
    "nombre": "test",
    "apellido": "test",
    "password": "1234"
},
"test2": {
    "nombre": "test",
    "apellido": "kubo",
    "password": "1234"
},
"test3": {
    "nombre": "test",
    "apellido": "kubo2",
    "password": "1234"
}
```

Quisiera conseguir el string test pasandole la posicion 0

Comment: En general, no tiene sentido tratar de acceder a una clave en un diccionario por la posición que ocupa en él. Hasta la versión 3.7 de python los diccionarios no garantizaban ningún orden interno (la primera clave podría incluso ser distinta en cada acceso al diccionario). En la 3.6 sí se respetaba el orden, pero era un detalle de implementación. A partir de la 3.7 se garantiza el orden de inserción, pero no es posible acceder a claves por posición. Para esto, mejor usa una lista.

Comment: Si deseas darle semántica al orden de inserción en un diccionario sin preocuparte por la versión del intérprete, usa OrderedDict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podemos crear una lista y hacer un `for` para recorrer todos los elementos de tu lista, e insertar cada uno en la nueva lista, esto para poder obtener el índice

```py
Personal = {
    "test": {
        "nombre": "test",
        "apellido": "test",
        "password": "1234"
    },
    "test2": {
        "nombre": "test",
        "apellido": "kubo",
        "password": "1234"
    },
    "test3": {
        "nombre": "test",
        "apellido": "kubo2",
        "password": "1234"
    }
}

indexes = []


for ind in Personal:
    indexes.append(Personal[ind])

print(indexes[0])
```

[image: Conseguir la clave de un diccionario a través de su posición en el diccionario]

Si lo que buscas es obtener solo el nombre puedes hacerlo reemplazando `Personal[ind]` por `ind`

```py
indexes = []


for ind in Personal:
    indexes.append(ind)

print(indexes[0])
```

[image: Conseguir la clave de un diccionario a traves de su posicion en el diccionario]

Answer (score 1):

### Python >= 3.7

Si la versión de Python es igual o superior a Python 3.7 entonces Python mantiene el orden de insercción en los diccionarios. Lo podrías hacer mediante el método de diccionario `.items()`. Aquí te dejo tu ejemplo:

```
personal = {
"test": {
    "nombre": "test",
    "apellido": "test",
    "password": "1234"
},
"test2": {
    "nombre": "test",
    "apellido": "kubo",
    "password": "1234"
},
"test3": {
    "nombre": "test",
    "apellido": "kubo2",
    "password": "1234"
}

list(personal.items())[1]
```

**Salida:**

```
('test2', {'nombre': 'test', 'apellido': 'kubo', 'password': '1234'})
```

Como ves el método `.items()` de los diccionarios de python devuelve una tupla, en el que el **primer elemento es la clave** y el **segundo elemento es el valor de la dichaclave** [Documentación diccionarios python items](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items).

Si quieres solo la clave, puedes utilizar indesación como en cualquier tupla, siguiendo con el ejemplo puedes hacer:

```
list(personal.items())[1][0]
```

**Salida:** `test2`

### Python <3.7

Si tu versión de Python es inferior, puedes utilizar `OrderecDict` de la STL de Python `collections`

```
from collections import OrderedDict

personal = OrderedDict({
    "test": {
        "nombre": "test",
        "apellido": "test",
        "password": "1234"
    },
    "test2": {
        "nombre": "test",
        "apellido": "kubo",
        "password": "1234"
    },
    "test3": {
        "nombre": "test",
        "apellido": "kubo2",
        "password": "1234"
    }
}
)


list(personal.items())[1][0]
```

**Salida:** (la misma)

```
('test2', {'nombre': 'test', 'apellido': 'kubo', 'password': '1234'})
```

Comment: Puedes ver más sobre como se hizo que los diccionarios mantuvieran el orden en [esta otra respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/388407/c%c3%b3mo-ordenar-una-parte-de-un-diccionario/388446?) por si es de interés.