# Como cambiar la clave de un diccionario?

Tags: python, python-3.x, diccionarios

Quiero cambiar la clave de un diccionario y que al cambiarlo, aparezca en la misma ubicación.

Muestro un ejemplo:

```
precio = {
    'Mesa': 100,
    'Silla': 200,
    'Madera': 300,
    'Marmol': 400,
    'Cemento': 500
}

precio['Butaca'] = precio.pop('Silla')

print(precio)
```

Y me devuelve:

```
{'Mesa': 100, 'Madera': 300, 'Marmol': 400, 'Cemento': 500, 'Butaca': 200}
```

La idea es que me devuelva:

```
{'Mesa': 100, 'Butaca': 200, 'Madera': 300, 'Marmol': 400, 'Cemento': 500}
```

Si alguien puede ayudarme. Gracias.

Comment: Algo que debes de saber es que los diccionarios al momento de imprimirse lo hacen de forma que estén ordenados, en este caso alfabéticamente

Comment: Un diccionario no tiene orden intrínseco. Un diccionario se accede por llave, no por ubicación.

Comment: @CandidMoe en versiones más recientes de Python, los diccionarios garantizan el orden de inserción. Es decir, si agregas una llave al diccionario, esta aparecerá a lo ultimo siempre.

Comment: @DanteS. Es un tema de concepto, de ocupar la estructura de datos adecuada al propósito. Usar un diccionario como lista revela confusión.

Comment: @CandidMoe No pareciera que quisiera hacer eso, pero quizá entiendo mal la pregunta. En cuanto a tu planteamiento, tienes razon, usar un diccionario como lista no tiene sentido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A partir de Python 3.7, los diccionarios mantienen el orden de inserción, [aquí se explica como se hace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/388407/c%c3%b3mo-ordenar-una-parte-de-un-diccionario). Por lo que se puede hacer lo que tu quieres hacer.

Teniendo en cuenta que **se mantiene el orden de insercción**, si quieres modificar una clave lo que debes de hacer es **crear un nuevo diccionario** con la clave modificada. Esto se puede hacer así:

```
precio = {
    'Mesa': 100,
    'Silla': 200,
    'Madera': 300,
    'Marmol': 400,
    'Cemento': 500
}

def modificar_clave(diccionario, vieja_clave, nueva_clave):
    return {clave if clave != vieja_clave else nueva_clave: valor for clave, valor in diccionario.items()}

modificar_clave(precio, "Silla", "Butaca")
```

**Salida:**

```
{'Mesa': 100, 'Butaca': 200, 'Madera': 300, 'Marmol': 400, 'Cemento': 500}
```

Lo podemos hacer en una linea usando [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/). Te explico lo que sucede paso por paso:

1. `for clave, valor in diccionario.items()`: `items()` es un método que nos devuelve las claves y los valores del diccionario lo que hacemos es iterar por las claves y los valores
2. `clave if clave != vieja_clave else nueva_clave: valor`: cada iteración comprobamos si la clave es la que queremos cambiar, si no es la que queremos cambiar, quedamos la clave como está, si es la que queremos cambiar, entonces la cambiamos. Esta forma de utilizar el condicional se llama [operador ternario](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Python)

Remarcar que **no estamos modificando el diccionario existente, ya que no es posible, si no que estamos creando un diccionario nuevo** modificando la clave indicada y haciendolo en el orden que queremos.

Answer (score 3):

lo que veo es que no quieres que te aparesca en la misma posicion, si no que tengas los valores ordenados. Entonces depues de haber agregado una nueva llave con el valor de la llave que has eliminado, pueded ordernar el diccionario por valor en el siguiente modo:

```
precio = {k: v for k, v in sorted(precio.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])}
```

Los diccionarios no se pueden ordenar (solo modificar sus valores), con este codigo estas creando un nuevo diccionario ordenadolo como lo quieres.

**UPDATE:**
Segun lo entendido lo que se quiere es poner un nuevo valor en la posicion de la vieja llave, sin importar su valor, entonces he creado esta funcion (funciona a partir de python 3.7 creo):

```
def insert_item(dic, item={}, pos=None):
    """
    Agrega un llave,valor al diccionario.
    Se agrega antes de la llave indicada.
    """
    from collections import OrderedDict
    d = {}
    # se sale si no es un diccionario:
    if not item or not isinstance(item, dict):
        print('Aborting. Argument item must be a dictionary.')
        return dic
    # se agrega simplemente, si no hay una posicion indicada: 
    if not pos:
        dic.update(item)
        return dic
    for item_k, item_v in item.items():
        for k, v in dic.items():
            # se agrega llave, valore en la posicion indicada
            if k == pos:
                d[item_k] = item_v
            d[k] = v
    return d
# llamando la funcion se usa en el siguiente modo
precio = insert_item(precio, {'Butaca': precio.get('Silla')}, 'Silla')
# despues se elimina el valor, si se elimina antes, la llave 'Silla no se va a encontrar
precio.pop('Silla')
```

Espero haber sido de ayuda

Saludos

Comment: Dices: *luego de haber cambiado la llave*. Pero los diccionarios son objetos inmutables cuyas llaves también lo son, pero sus valores si pueden tener objetos mutable

Comment: He corregido las respuesta

Comment: Perfecto!! ..

Comment: Justo coincidio que los numeros estén de menor a mayor, pero fue a modo de ejemplo, la idea es que aparezca en la misma posicion porque el diccionario se complementa con otro diccionario.